# node version vs npm outdated

Tags: node.js, npm

earlier this year I installed node 10.15.3 then I updated npm to 6.9.0. Since then I have encountered some anomalies and want to rollback npm.

I ran the following commands

```
npm install npm@6.4.1
npm --version
#6.4.1
node --version
#10.15.3
```

Then I an `npm outdated -g` and got this result

[image]

I tried running `npm install node@10.15.3` which threw an exception. Then I tried repairing 10.15.3 and rebooting the machine.

Why is `npm outdated -g` reporting a lower version than `node --version`?

Comment: This looks pretty screwy. It seems like you have installed node globally as an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node). When I run `npm outdated -g` it doesn't show my node at all. Maybe worth figuring out how to remove that and install [NVM](http://nvm.sh) to manage node versions.

Comment: I agree, if I look at my local machine node does not appear either

Answer (score 0):

My resolution was

1. uninstall nodejs 10.15.3 via the msi
2. delete `[user]/appdata/roaming/npm*` I had npm and npm-cahche, so I deleted both
3. reboot machine
4. install nodejs 10.15.3
5. run `npm outdated -g`

no packages outdated.
So it looked like the roaming data, and/or cache, was the issue.